Timeout when connecting to VPN using L2TP with IPsec PSK
I was connecting to this VPN using Fortinet's Windows client until a week ago, then I switched to Debian 12.6 and I can't connect it by any means anymore
First, I tried Fortinet's Linux client, but it disconnects the moment I try to login. Then I tried to connect by NetworkManager with strongswan and L2TP (with IPsec enabled) and both returned me the same timeout messages. This is not an issue about credentials typed wrong, I checked the logs and found the following:
<warn>  [1722525040.5843] vpn[0x55a30a580380,e8d56050-b5d3-4e84-9737-b1a280396d6e,"UEL"]: failed to connect: 'couldn't look up L2TP VPN gateway IP address '
<warn>  [1722525085.9583] vpn[0x55a30a580100,e8d56050-b5d3-4e84-9737-b1a280396d6e,"UEL"]: failed to connect: 'Timeout was reached'
First log is for the wrong IP and the second for the correct, so at least it seems to be able to find the connection
For now, I'm using Fortinet on Windows on another computer to do what I need, but it is a big inconvenience to boot it up just for connecting into the VPN

If the connection works with the Windows bult-in L2TP/IPsec client, it should work with NetworkManager-l2tp also. Can you confirm it works with the Windows bult-in L2TP/IPsec client?
There is a NetworkManager-fortisslvpn client that works with the Fortinet SSLVPN server.

@DouglasKosovic tried using the Windows's native VPN (and Android as well) but got the same problem. I don't understand so much about VPN's, but the only available connection provided was for IPsec

If L2TP isn't configured on the VPN server, I don't think there is any out of the box NetworkManager VPN plugin that will work with FortiGate. Some have had success with NetworkManager-vpnc with a modified and patched vpnc to work with newer FortiGate versions, issues described here:
https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiGate/Technical-Note-Interoperability-between-FortiOS-and-VPNC/ta-p/191616

I think you'll have more luck with using strongSwan (but not the NetworkManager strongswan plugin). See:
https://community.fortinet.com/t5/Support-Forum/strongSwan-on-linux-as-IPSec-VPN-client/td-p/23146/page/2?m=179755
and
https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/interop/fortinet.html
